# Pinout: RJ-45 to DB25 adapter for SunBlade 2000

Tags: sun, serial, adapter

Our suite got new carpet this weekend, and as I was moving the machines out of the way I pulled apart the serial adapter.  The RJ-45 clip held fast, and the metal body was screwed tight to the machine - so the metal body pulled out of the plastic shell, and all of the sockets pulled off of the interior pins.  It pulled away at a slight angle, so I can tell that pins **1**, **2**, **3**, **4**, **7**, and **20** were connected - they're bent just a little.

I found [this page](http://www.sunhelp.org/unix-serial-port-resources/serial-pinouts/), which includes pinouts for RJ-45 adapters to DB25 and DB9... but they specify 8 wires, and the adapter I broke only has 6; also the color scheme is different.  My adapter is labeled
     **3230289-02 "SUN"**
but I have not been able to find whose part number that is.

[image: busted adapter showing part number and bent pins]
[image: busted adapter showing wire colors]

I'm going to try to transpose those instructions from 8 wires to 6 and hope it works - but I'm hoping that someone out there has seen (or HAS?) an adapter like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to transpose the pinouts I found on the Sun page, and the Cisco pinouts on the page that @mulaz recommended, and I couldn't find any way to reconcile them with the previously-bent pins.  Fortunately, however, I was able to reach the company that installed the SunBlade (and the piece of equipment that it's controlling, which is probably more to the point!)  The tech found a spare adapter of the same model, took it apart, and read me the pinout over the phone.  I'm posting it here in case someone else has the same issue...

```
DB25    Color      RJ45  

1       Red         5
2       Black       6
3       Yellow      3
4       Brown       2
7       Green       4
20      Orange      7
```

(6 wires only - pin 1 and 8 are missing)

[image: adapter taken apart, showing connections to RJ45 jack and metal body]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your server, but I've used a normal "Cisco" DB9->RJ45 cable with Sun Netra 240, and it worked fine. Maybe if you compare it to [this](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/hw/routers/ps214/products_tech_note09186a00801f5d85.shtml), and see if the pins fit? (1 and 8 are not connected, see if yours match, and don't forget about the DB9->DB25 conversion).

Comment: Thanks!  It's possible that one of those might have worked, but I couldn't reconcile it with the part I actually had.  (Since most serial connections don't use all the available pins, there can be multiple "correct" configurations; also, connectors that are missing a handshake pin can work under perfect conditions and then fail when real life strikes.  So I wanted to make sure it was identical to the original configuration.)  Thanks for the assist, though!